List processes over 20% CPU usage
I am trying to find a process that uses all our CPU when it crashes, we know it's IIS w3wp.exe since I made this to execute on high load and dump all processes using more than 20% CPU:
(Get-Counter '\Process(*)% Processor Time').CounterSamples | Where-Object {$_.CookedValue -gt 20}> processname.txt
However - we have multiple instances of IIS / w3wp.exe running so I can't pinpoint the path or ID to narrow down the process and which website is causing the issue.
I found this which lists path but how do I bring the two scripts together so it only lists ones using above 20% CPU:
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "name = 'w3wp.exe'" | Select-Object CommandLine
Can anyone help?
Thanks
